# When the Duration.between() in Java DateTime return negative value

Tags: java, datetime, duration, timezone-offset, jsr310

I am preaparing for the Java OCP Test, and in the mock test there is a question about Java DateTime like this:

> Given that New York is 3 hours ahead of Los Angeles, what will the
>   following code print?
>
> ```
> LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.of(2017, 12, 02, 6, 0, 0);         
> ZonedDateTime nyZdt = ldt.atZone(nyZone);
> ZonedDateTime laZdt = ldt.atZone(laZone);
> Duration d = Duration.between(nyZdt, laZdt);
> System.out.println(d);
> ```

And the correct answer is PT3H but I am a little bit confused here is if the book gives the wrong answer or not?

Given is NY 3 hours ahead of LA, does it mean, for example, NY is 5:00 and then LA will be 2:00. So the Duration.between(5,2) should be PT-3H because according to the Javadoc: `The result of this method can be a negative period if the end is before the start. To guarantee to obtain a positive duration call abs() on the result.`, and in this case **"2"** is **before** **"5"** so the result should be PT-3H, not PT3H.

What do you think, which one is correct?

Comment: When it's 6am in LA, it's 9am in NYC. So 6am in LA occurs 3h after 6am in NYC.

Comment: On a minor nit: don't prefix integer literals with zero unless you really intend to write them in octal.

Comment: In your example, `nyZdt` = New York 6am which is 3 hours **before** `laZdt` = Los Angeles 6am, so the end is **not** before the start.

Comment: The best way to find out if the book is right is to run the code (spoiler alert: [the book is right](http://ideone.com/hSZaKB)).

Comment: Funny that they give the day of month as an octal value, `02`. It makes no difference in this case (but the 8th of the month would have to be written `010`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Duration.between` returns the difference between the two instants. For `LocalDateTime`, this means the correct answer requires normalizing the time zones. Since the same local hour in LA is *later* than in NY, the result is positive.

At 6:00 AM in NY, it's 3:00 AM in LA, which means that 3 hours will elapse until it's 6:00 AM in LA.
Conversely, at 6:00 AM in LA, it's 9:00 AM in NY, which means 3 hours have ellapsed since 6:00 AM NY.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.of(2017, 12, 02, 6, 0, 0);         
ZonedDateTime nyZdt = ldt.atZone(nyZone); // 6:00 AM NY = 3:00 AM LA
ZonedDateTime laZdt = ldt.atZone(laZone); // 6:00 AM LA = 9:00 AM NY
Duration d = Duration.between(nyZdt, laZdt); // 9:00 AM NY - 6:00 AM NY = 3H   OR 3:00 AM LA - 6:00 AM LA = 3H
```

Answer (score 0):

3 hours is correct. Simply run the code..

```
@Test
public void test1() throws Exception {

    LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.of(2017, 12, 02, 6, 0, 0);
    ZonedDateTime nyZdt = ldt.atZone(ZoneId.of("America/New_York"));
    ZonedDateTime laZdt = ldt.atZone(ZoneId.of("America/Los_Angeles"));
    Duration d = Duration.between(nyZdt, laZdt);
    System.out.println(d.toHours());


}
```

Comment: Although this may be technically correct, this is not the answer to the question, which clearly states: "Given that New York is 3 hours ahead of Los Angeles, what will the following code print?"

Answer (score 0):

Another approach will be to convert `nyZdt` and `laZdt` to `Instant`.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.of(2017, 12, 02, 6, 0, 0);  

ZoneId nyZone = ZoneId.of("America/New_York");
ZonedDateTime nyZdt = ldt.atZone(nyZone);
System.out.println(nyZdt.toInstant()); //Prints 2017-12-02T11:00:00Z

ZoneId laZone = ZoneId.of("America/Los_Angeles");
ZonedDateTime laZdt = ldt.atZone(laZone);
System.out.println(laZdt.toInstant()); //Prints 2017-12-02T14:00:00Z

Duration d = Duration.between(nyZdt, laZdt);
System.out.println(d); //Prints PT3H
```

In this example you can see more clearly why the minus sign does not appear in your output. As you can see `end` **IS NOT** before `start`. Start is `2017-12-02T11:00:00Z` and end is `2017-12-02T14:00:00Z`, with other words, LA is after NY, so the difference is: **`PT3H`**.

Answer (score 0):

What do you do if you are asked to find the difference between `2 km 300 m`<sup>1</sup> and `1020 m 45 cm`?

***Your answer***: I will convert each distance in the **same** unit and then subtract one from the other.

This is exactly what you need to do in order to understand and solve this problem. You need to convert both the date-times to the **same** timezone and then find the duration.

### [`ZonedDateTime#withZoneSameInstant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#withZoneSameInstant-java.time.ZoneId-)

Use it to get a copy of a `ZonedDateTime` with a different time-zone, retaining the instant. In simple terms, it will return you the local date-time in the target time-zone.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ZoneId nyZone = ZoneId.of("America/New_York");
        ZoneId laZone = ZoneId.of("America/Los_Angeles");
        LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.of(2017, 12, 02, 6, 0, 0);
        ZonedDateTime nyZdt = ldt.atZone(nyZone);
        ZonedDateTime laZdt = ldt.atZone(laZone);
        System.out.println("laZd ----------------------------> " + laZdt);

        // Convert the nyZdt to LA date-time
        ZonedDateTime nyZdtConverted = nyZdt.withZoneSameInstant(laZone);
        System.out.println("nyZdt converted to LA date-time -> " + nyZdtConverted);

        Duration d = Duration.between(nyZdt, laZdt);
        System.out.println(d);

        d = Duration.between(nyZdtConverted, laZdt);
        System.out.println(d);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
laZd ----------------------------> 2017-12-02T06:00-08:00[America/Los_Angeles]
nyZdt converted to LA date-time -> 2017-12-02T03:00-08:00[America/Los_Angeles]
PT3H
PT3H
```

As you can see, `nyZdt` is `3` hours before `laZd` and hence the duration is `PT3H`.

---

<sup>1</sup> km stands for kilometres, m stands for metre and cm stands for centimetre